# CustomChrome issue with WindowStyle=None, restoring window

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's some context for my problem:

I downloaded the [CustomChromeLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library), 
and changed 
the Shell Reference from Microsoft.Windows.Shell to System.Windows.Shell, which is the same thing in framework 4.5.

Working from the CustomChromeSample, I am able to show a CustomChrome window, but IF I change the following properties in MainWindow.xaml:

1. WindowStyle=None
2. AllowTransparency=True
3. Background=Transparent

(note that WindowStyle=None alone causes the issue)

then, IF I change the WindowState in this sequence:

1. Normal (init state)
2. Maximized (click button maximize)
3. Minimized (click button minimized)
4. Normal (click program icon in TaskBar)

then the program icon disappears from the TaskBar and Ive no idea why.

So, does anybody have an idea?
Also, is there a place where I could upload the code for you to see?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, never mind. I used MahApps.MetroWindow and copy pasted their theme so I could change it how I wanted while keeping all the functionalities of a normal window. Their code is really great.